# Allow Firefox snap access to USB security keys

Tags: firefox, snap, 22.04

On Ubuntu 22.04 using the Firefox snap (latest, revision 1300).
I'm trying to use a security key with GitHub, Cloudflare and various other sites. When the site prompts me to use my key, the Firefox prompt window ("This site wants to authenticate you ... Connect a security key now, or cancel") shows up but no matter what I do the key does not seem to be recognised, or even seen, by Firefox.

Security keys worked fine on the .deb version of Firefox.

How do I configure snap to allow access to security keys?

Output of `snap connections firefox`:

```
Interface                 Plug                            Slot                             Notes
audio-playback            firefox:audio-playback          :audio-playback                  -
audio-record              firefox:audio-record            :audio-record                    -
avahi-observe             firefox:avahi-observe           :avahi-observe                   -
browser-support           firefox:browser-sandbox         :browser-support                 -
camera                    firefox:camera                  :camera                          -
content[gnome-3-38-2004]  firefox:gnome-3-38-2004         gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     firefox:gtk-3-themes            gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
content[icon-themes]      firefox:icon-themes             gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
content[sound-themes]     firefox:sound-themes            gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
cups-control              firefox:cups-control            :cups-control                    -
dbus                      -                               firefox:dbus-daemon              -
desktop                   firefox:desktop                 :desktop                         -
desktop-legacy            firefox:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy                  -
gsettings                 firefox:gsettings               :gsettings                       -
hardware-observe          firefox:hardware-observe        :hardware-observe                -
home                      firefox:home                    :home                            -
joystick                  firefox:joystick                :joystick                        -
mpris                     -                               firefox:mpris                    -
network                   firefox:network                 :network                         -
network-observe           firefox:network-observe         -                                -
opengl                    firefox:opengl                  :opengl                          -
personal-files            firefox:dot-mozilla-firefox     :personal-files                  -
removable-media           firefox:removable-media         :removable-media                 -
screen-inhibit-control    firefox:screen-inhibit-control  :screen-inhibit-control          -
system-files              firefox:etc-firefox-policies    :system-files                    -
system-packages-doc       firefox:system-packages-doc     :system-packages-doc             -
u2f-devices               firefox:u2f-devices             :u2f-devices                     -
unity7                    firefox:unity7                  :unity7                          -
upower-observe            firefox:upower-observe          :upower-observe                  -
wayland                   firefox:wayland                 :wayland                         -
x11                       firefox:x11                     :x11                             -
```

Note how `:hardware-observe` is already connected.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my security key isn't on the list of U2F devices recognised by snaps. [The list (of hardware vendor/ID combinations) can be seen at the snapcrafter Github.](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/master/interfaces/builtin/u2f_devices.go)

To remedy this, try and find your security key's IDs and submit it in an issue/pull request to get it added. Your keys should then work with the next core update.

Answer (score 2):

Should be: `snap connect firefox:u2f-devices` but it does not work either for me :(

The file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.firefox.rules` simply does not cover most of U2F devices.

I have added to that file my device (which details you can spot in your dmesg):

```
# u2f-devices
# MK FIDO
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0416", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c138", TAG+="snap_firefox_firefox"
```

After adding, restarted firefox, and unplugged and plugged the key.

It works now! (until new snap comes and then you need to start the game again...)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with latest Ledger Nano S Plus and I finally solved it:
Prerequisites:
Ledger Nano S Plus
Firefox installed from snap

1. DO `lsusb -v` and gather `product id`
2. `sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.firefox.rule` find the line with `Ledger Blue + Nano S + Nano X`

should look like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c97", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000|0001|0004|0005|0015|1005|1015|4005|4015|5015", TAG+="snap_firefox_firefox"
```

what you need to do is append your new productId to the end of the attributes.

4. `sudo systemctl reload apparmor.service`

Hope that it helps